# Highest value of y-axis is not shown

Tags: highcharts

When using `$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', { ...` the highest value of the y-Axis is not shown. If I try it without `StockChart`, it is ok.
Example in http://jsfiddle.net/h5bSV/3/ the value 430 is missing.

Is there a possibility to show this label?

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        title: {
            text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
        },
        tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){
                return "open: " + this.points[0].point.open + 'close: ' + this.points[0].point.close + ' high: ' + this.points[0].point.high + ' low:' + this.points[0].point.low;
            }

        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            type: 'candlestick',
            data : data,
            tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}
        }]
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [ShowLastLabel](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.showLastLabel) as true.